# Can kubernetes Ingress Nginx be autoscaled?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

When the Ingress Nginx controller reach its full capacity does it auto scale?
Is Kubernetes Ingress even scalable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, the NGINX ingress controller is indeed scalable -- it pulls its entire configuration from the Kubernetes API server and is in itself basically stateless.

In practice, this depends very much on how your ingress controller is set up. First of all, the ingress controller will not auto-scale by itself. If you have deployed it using a `Deployment` controller, you can use [horizontal pod autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) as described in the documentation. If you have deployed it using a `DaemonSet`, the ingress controller will automatically scale up and down with your cluster (maybe even automatically, if you're using the [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler)).

In both scenarios, you're going to need a `Service` definition (possibly of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`, to allow for external traffic) that matches all pods created by the deployment/daemon set to distribute traffic among them.

Comment: when i have more then one NGINX pod, how will the NGINX loadbalancer (default is least conn) work? does it have shared memory like option between instances like with zone and worker process?

Comment: Ingress controllers are nothing else than regular Kubernetes pods. There is no shared memory between them, so there won't be any kind of global "least connection" load balancing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to autoscale nginx ingress controller in two ways:

1. Kubernetes' Horizontal Pod Autoscaler.
2. Use multiple nginx ingress controllers per https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/multiple-ingress-controllers. In this approach, you would need multiple nginx ingress resources too to load-balance the traffic to the backend pods. https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example has example/sample ingress resource for nginx.

The "least connection" (`least conn`) configuration is not related to autoscaling of nginx. It is the load-balancing algorithm used by nginx and can be changed to others (`round robin` or `ip hash`) in the nginx configuration file (`nginx.conf`) using ConfigMaps.

Comment: thanks! but if i want the least conn because i use nginx as a load-balancer as well, how can the data be shared? it seems like the load-balancer is not scaleable

Comment: There is no data to be shared as the nginx ingress controller is stateless and gets all the data from the kubernetes api server.

Comment: @xFiler glad to help, upvote my answer if you think it is useful!